# How to disable the hover effect if another element is rendered ontop (higher zIndex)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface

Hi all I'm pretty new to react and css, I've come across this problem while trying to develop a teams-like weekly calendar. Hopefully somebody can point me to the right direction.
I have basically generated a table that highlights the cell and the whole column once the mouse passes over.
[table grid on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycfsT.png)

with the following CSS to achieve the result:

```
.weekdayList:hover, .hourCell:hover {
    background-color: rgba(33, 149, 243, 0.15)
  }
```

Now, in the cell I have a button that opens a new dialog and lets me create an event and save it.
Upon exiting the dialog the calendar is updated thanks to the useEffect hook, a card element will be rendered above (zIndex = 1) the cell originally clicked to show basic info of the event that was just created.

My problem is that when I mouse hover the new event card, the cell and the column below it still feels the hover effect, still highlighting everything behind the card element. I don't want this to happen since I want to keep that element semi-transparent.

[highilight behind event card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvBiz.png)

this is the code used to generate columns and cells:

```
<div className="weekdayList">
 Some cycle code here
 <div className="hourCell">
  {checkEventExists && (<CalEventCard />)}
   <Button>button with action</Button>
 </div>
</div>
```

and this is the sx override inside the CalEventCard element:

```
<Card
sx={{
                zIndex: 1,
                position: 'absolute',
                height: `${40 * height * 2}px`, 
                width: '95%',
                background: 'rgb(255 250 255 / 40%)', 
                border: '1px solid',
                borderColor: theme.palette.secondary[200],
                ':hover': {
                    boxShadow: '0 2px 14px 0 rgb(32 40 45 / 15%)'
                },
                ...sx
            }}
>
```

Is there a simple way to make so that the hover effects of hourCell and weekdayList are turned off if a CalEventCard is above them?

Reading some CSS tutorials I have come across some attributes like "isolation" and "pointer-event" but I couldn't solve the issue with those or probably didn't understand their use deeply.

Comment: you could try use `.hourCell:has(CalEventCardClass):hover {background-color: transparent}` to remove the background colour: [css has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Comment: @Pete this worked (without the last :hover string) only to remove the background to the .hourCell class. However the .weekdayList column still feels the mouse overing even if im pointing on CalEventCard. It still is a little step forward, thanks